# Link in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm not sure how to even go about looking up the answer to this question, so I apologize for not having done any research before posting. I have never touched ASP.NET before. I migrated one IIS project to a different server, and it's working as intended, except for one thing. I believe the below code snippet is responsible for creating links in a table, but it's hardcoding the links to the old URL instead of the new one. I'm not sure how to edit the ASP.NET to correct the problem and point to the new server instead. Any thoughts? Is a different code snippet responsible?

The code:

```
    <%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvPublicPositionList" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_PublicPositionList" Width="800">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbGotoJobDescription" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Select"
                            Text='<% #Eval("Title") %>' PostBackUrl='<% #Eval("URL") %>' ></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Department" HeaderText="Department" SortExpression="Department" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource_PublicPositionList" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:JobDescriptionsConnectionStringPublic2005 %>"
            SelectCommand="spSelectPublicPositionList" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:JobDescriptionsConnectionStringPublic2005 %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tblDepartments]"></asp:SqlDataSource>


    </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The link format:

```
javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("gvPublicPositionList$ctl02$lbGotoJobDescription", "", false, "", "CORRECT LINK BUT TO OLD SERVER", false, true))
```

Comment: You're using Eval to pull the URL field from the data source. Check the data source that's bound the to the repeater. The source probably has an old URL you need to update. Depending on how your data source gets initialized, it's likely that the old link lies in your database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL is coming from some data source in the code, so you'll have to find where that's getting populated. The `<% #Eval("URL") %>` code means that you're bound to something called `URL` - could be a database value, could be a property of some object, no way to know without seeing the data source.

So find out where this control is being populated (it will probably look something like `someRepeater.DataSource = someDataSource;`, and that will tell you what you need to change.

Comment: Or there could be an SqlDataSource or ObjectDataSource control on the .aspx page, so check those too.

Comment: The only thing I see is a couple lines above: `<asp:GridView ID="gvPublicPositionList" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_PublicPositionList" Width="800">`. Could that be it?

Comment: That should be it - look for something called `SqlDataSource_PublicPositionList` - that should define the query that runs to pull the data, and from there, just find and update the actual data.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still lost. I pasted the full page code in the OP if you're able/willing to help me narrow it down further. I found the data source but I'm not sure how it's getting URL from it.

Comment: @Vaindil It is a Stored Procedure, in your database called `spSelectPublicPositionList`. One of the columns its returning is called 'URL' which is where the link is coming from.

Comment: @Vaindil So what you need to do is go into the `spSelectPublicPositionList` Stored Procedure in your database and figure out what view or table it obtains the URL column from. If it's in a view, then find the view for that table. Once you know the table, then update the values to point to the new url.

Comment: Ah, that helped tremendously. Thank you so much for your help everyone!